# Can we declare the reference variable as String for the char array?

Tags: java, string, char

```
           char[] name = new char[]{'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'}  // I know this is valid

          String[] name = new char[]{'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'} // is this valid too?
```

Please let me know if we can declare the reference variable type as String for the above

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: NO. Check this http://ideone.com/wQN2Lb . Also this can be easily and better verified by trying it yourself

Comment: Thanks VusP, but ideone is too slow

Comment: Hi Andrew Barber, How can this question be unclear to you? it is just basic java and even beginners have answered this questions. Why have you put this question on hold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not valid

how ever you can do following:

```
String[] name=new String[]{"h", "e", "l", "l", "o"};
```

or

```
String name=new String(new char[]{'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'});
```